# First day of internship

Tags: software-industry, new-job, job-offer, internship

I am joining high tech company in Silicon Valley very soon. HR didn't ask me to bring any particular documents on first day.

What should I need to show security at entrance on my first day? Just an offer letter will do? Or my name is enough?

Comment: Ask them. Send an email to your hiring manager or someone else who was involved with your hiring.

Comment: If the internship is paid expect to have to complete the I-9 form, which will requires you to bring specific and maybe multiple forms of identification. Ask to make sure.

Comment: Driver's license, social security card and a pen are enough to get all the paperwork taken care of.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations!

The most important thing to bring is yourself, ready to learn and work. Make sure you know who to ask for when you turn up at the front desk. They'll tell you what else they need.

But I've brought multiple interns onboard, so I know as well.

You're going to need to fill out an I-9 form (right to work in the US). This requires some identification. Look at the last page of this pdf for a list. http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf  Other commentary on your question notwithstanding, a valid passport will do if you're a US national.

If you're getting paid you'll need a blank and voided check from your bank account, so they can set up your direct deposit correctly.

It will be fine if you don't have these documents on your first day, especially if they haven't written you a letter or email saying what to bring. They'll let you know what and when.

Comment: It's a first day on the job, not an interview. Please look at the pdf I linked for the list of right-to-work verification documents required by *la migra.* A US national needs proof of identity and proof of citizenship to complete that form. A passport serves both purposes. If you think that's overkill bring a state-issued photo id card *and* a birth certificate or original social security card.  Is it overkill? Yes. Talk to your representative and senator in the US congress about that. I wish I were making this up. I'm not.

Comment: US employers who don't keep I-9 forms for each employee, citizen or non-citizen, are out of compliance, your belief to the contrary notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Some form of identification (ID / drivers licence / passport) will probably do for most purposes (although even that might not be necessary).

I can't imagine the offer letter would be necessary, as they were the ones who made you the offer, after all, but it certainly can't hurt to take it along.

Without explicitly telling you what you should take along, they shouldn't expect you to take much more than just a form of identification.

I do suggest you also have the name of someone in the company who can confirm your internship handy on the off chance that they forgot to tell security about you, or the security guidelines they have in place makes preconfirmed entry difficult or impossible.

I can't guarantee that this will be sufficient though - if you'd rather be safe than sorry, you'll have to confirm with them (with an e-mail or phone call to whomever you liaised with).

---

Pen and paper also doesn't hurt - having a pen (that works) handy to fill in or sign anything and popping out a notepad to make notes of important things might help with the first impressions.

Comment: I've never encountered a U.S. company that was interested in seeing my passport.  I'd suggest the OP just bring his wallet and the things he normally carries in there (driver's license or equivalent government-issued ID).  Or even better, send that email and get specific details from the employer.

Comment: So mostly , when I say my name at the entrance, security person will be already aware of my entry ? :)

Comment: @aroth For an I9, which may be required for paid internships, you will need proof of US citizenship in the form of passport or birth certificate. He should definitely check if he needs either of those with him

Comment: @user19077 yes, if the company has any sort of organisational skills the security at the gate will be aware to expect you.

Comment: @user19077 Likely yes, but not necessarily, although you shouldn't see it as your problem to prove to security that you're supposed to be there - just saying you're starting an internship there, possibly proving who you are, and possibly having the name of someone they can contact to confirm handy should be sufficient.